# Uncaught TypeError: game.cache.getSound(...).play is not a function when retrieving sound from Phaser.Cache

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a phaser game with 2 different states, ie the `preloadState` and the `gameState`. The sound files were loaded first using `Phaser.Loader` in the `preloadState`. However, upon finished loading and entering `gameState`, I am not able to retrieve the said sound file.

**Call stack:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.cache.getSound(...).play is not a function
(anonymous function) @ game.js:232
Phaser.SignalBinding.execute @ phaser.js:29960
Phaser.Signal.dispatch @ phaser.js:29765
Phaser.Events.(anonymous function) @ phaser.js:44440
Phaser.InputHandler._pointerOverHandler @ phaser.js:40080
Phaser.Pointer.processInteractiveObjects @ phaser.js:38363
Phaser.Pointer.move @ phaser.js:38275
Phaser.Mouse.onMouseMove @ phaser.js:36385
_onMouseMove @ phaser.js:36275
```

**Below is my code:**

**preload.js**

```
    var preloadState = {
        preload: function() {
        // set preload sprite here
        // ...
        // Audio files
        this.load.audio('button_click','assets/button_click.ogg');
    },
    create: function() {
        this.button_click_sound = this.add.audio('button_click'); 
    }
```

**game.js**

```
var gameState = {
    create:function() {
         game.cache.getSound('button_click').play();    // Error here
}
```

**main.js**

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(432,800,Phaser.AUTO);
game.state.add('gameState', gameState);
game.state.add('preloadState', preloadState);
game.state.start('preloadState');
```

According to http://phaser.io/docs/2.2.2/Phaser.Cache.html#getSound, the `getSound` method returns Phaser.Sound object, but its `play()` method is not callable?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```js
var gameState = {
  create:function() {
    var button_sound = game.add.audio('button_click');
    button_sound.play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out the reason why the `play()` method is not accessible.

The cache stores the audio data in the form of objects but not `Phaser.Sound` instances, and hence the method cannot be called.

The code where the object creation and insertion into the cache can be found in the `addSound` method in `Phaser.Sound`:

`this._cache.sound[key] = {
            url: url,
            data: data,
            isDecoding: false,
            decoded: decoded,
            webAudio: webAudio,
            audioTag: audioTag,
            locked: this.game.sound.touchLocked
        };`

Also I think the doc for this method `Phaser.Cache#getSound` should be updated to not use `Phaser.Sound` as return value but the sound object.